# Odd interface when running sudo ifconfig

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, interface, ifconfig

So, I've noticed an odd looking interface... Apparently, it has it's own MAC address (which I don't even know where it came from... Attempting to perform an OUI lookup on it returns no results...)

Now, I do use the built in PPTP VPN service in Ubuntu (yeah, I know PPTP as a protocol is insecure), but I don't think it would spawn it's own interface like that. Attempting to remove it works (using `sudo ifconfig enx6e72e759174c:1` down) , but it returns on reboot.

Any ideas on where it could have came from?

Note the first interface...
[image]

Comment: Please don't provide information as image which can be posted as text.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Dell D3100 docking station with my laptop and have this same odd interface issue. The docking station has an Ethernet port on it, and when connected to the docking station (via USB) the extra Ethernet interface is shown in `ifconfig`. When disconnected it goes away. I would ask if you are also connected to some hardware with an Ethernet port, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so this is the answer that solves the same odd interface problem for me.

PS. Here is the entry from my `ifconfig` for reference:

```
riffic@yavin4:~$ ifconfig
enx9cebe81e35fc Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:eb:e8:1e:35:fc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```